# How do I delete a face?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

By hollow, I mean that I want only the sides and the base of the frustum to be visible. I already have a 3D Cone Frustum so now I only want to subtract the inner regions from the cone. So, my question is of course, how to do that ? I thought of using boolean but it only shows the option of a cone, so is it possible to use another one as a boolean modifier ? if yes, then how. I am a total noob and hence forgive me if its a bad question.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In *Edit Mode* enable *Face select* right click on the top face you want to remove.

[image]

Then press <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Delete</kbd>. This shows the *Delete* popup menu, where you can select *Faces*.

[image]

Comment: Though this can remove the face but this removes both faces. I only want the top face to die and want the bottom face to stay

Comment: doing that leaves me with this which is exactly not what I want... http://tinypic.com/r/30ivm2g/8

Comment: SO, @stacker what is it that I'm doing wrong ???

Comment: @user3219 You probably had the other face select as well, press 'A' to select/deselect all before clicking the face you want to remove.

Comment: I tried deselecting all faces then clicking the face I want to delete, but it refuses to get selected, how do you select a face exactly, i tried everything you said, @stacker

Comment: @user3219 Are you sure that you're in edit and not in object mode? Right click selects the face.

Comment: Note that this will result in a non-manifold mesh (the "walls" have no thickness). You can add thickness with a *Solidify modifier*.

Comment: For the basic functions of blender please use the resources that have been put together in the beginner reference guide: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/40/beginners-reference